Как узнать SSID подключённого WiFi. Android Unity
Необходимо узнать, к какому Wi-Fi подключен пользователь Android-приложения на данный момент. Как это можно реализовать?

Тут есть ответ на ваш вопрос: https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-wifi-manager.1426377/ Только не забудьте о правильных разрешениях в манифесте: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47847947/5479247
